# Battery Pack discharge behaviour

Tags: batteries, simulation, lithium-ion, discharge, modeling

i want to simulate the discharging behaviour of several battery packs/modules connected in series to simulate a discharge machine for a recycling facility. I wanted to simulate possible current/voltage spikes in my circuit when removing a battery from the circuit, once its sufficiently discharged. So my question is, if someone could advice me on the model i need for the battery pack/module.

I thank you for any advice!

Comment: Batteries are like charged capacitors with some resistors (one in parallel and one in series). With that model, you get 4 numbers that characterize: the capacitance, 2 resistances, and the initial voltage.  To make it better, thone 4 become functions of other values such as temperature, direction of current, etc